# how to replace 'table a'.'column b' with 'table b'.'column b' if 'table a'.'column b' matches 'table b'.'column a'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables relating to products that my company sells being superseded by new products, this has over time led to multiples occurring.

I have used the following query over and over until I have been left with 2 products in the final table...

```
CREATE TABLE mar15a    
SELECT x.sku, x.superseded_sku FROM table x
JOIN table y ON y.sku = x.superseded_sku
```

I now have 5 tables (mar15a, mar15b, ... mar15e)
they follow this structure.

```
------------------------------------
| sku            | superseded_sku  |
------------------------------------
| PartA          | PartC           |
| PartB          | PartC           |
| PartC          | PartD           |
```

So how do I now combine these to end up with one final list that shows the supersedes from table E in table D, etc?

I hope this makes sense, my brain hurts today.

There's a [sqlfiddle available here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52228) to give more of an idea, I've included part of table A and all of table B.

---

I've tried this...

SET a.`superseded_sku` = b.`superseded_sku`
FROM mar15a a
WHERE a.`superseded_sku` = b.sku
INNER JOIN mar15b b ON b.sku = a.sku

Which doesn't work but should give a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: This will be hard to solve without some sample data. Can you stick something in sqlfiddle.com ?

Is there any reason why you couldn't just have one table with a self-referential foreign key?

Comment: @SimonWoolf

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52228

Hopefully that link works, I don't believe that foreign keys are an option as I'm using the MYISAM engine.

Comment: Let me get this right?

You want to know what the very first superseded product was, and what its current replacement is? so, for example:

Where sku 123 is replaced by sku 456, then later sku 456 is replaced by sku 789, you want a table with sku: 789 and supersended_sku: 123
?

Comment: The other way around, I want to wind up with sku 123 superseded to sku 789 so that it cuts out the intermediate parts that are also superseded. So in short if it currently goes 123-456-789 I want to wind up with 123-789.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit hazy on what you want, but will attempt a solution and then revise it if I misunderstood.

As far as I can see, what you want is just accomplished with a query like this:

```
SELECT
    a.superseded_sku, d.sku
FROM
    mar15a a                JOIN

    mar15b b ON
        a.sku = b.superseded_sku    JOIN

    mar15c c ON
        b.sku = c.superseded_sku    JOIN

    marl5d d ON
        c.sku = d.superseded_sku
```

If you can explain why this *wouldn't* produce the result you want, I can revise as necessary . . .

Comment: This only winds up with the data from the last table. I originally had 1 table which had all of the supersedes included. I did a similar thing to this in order to wind up with each `step` of supersedes (as each supersede could have it's own supersede).

so I'm looking to replace mar15a.superseded_sku with mar15b.superseded_sku IF mar15a.superseded_sku = mar15b.sku and so on.

This idea being that I end up with the same sku column as I have in mar15a but the corresponding supersede_sku will have changed to it's final supersede to date.

Comment: Thank you for your continued effort by the way, I really appreciate it :)>

Answer (score 0):

From the data in your sqlfiddle, it looks like you have superseded skus being superseded themselves within one table. This makes the problem significantly more difficult and probably impossible using a single query.

As you don't know in advance how many times a sku has been superseded, I don't see any way you can avoid processing the data outside of SQL. You would have to perform a validation check on the results to see if any superseded skus have been superseded again.

The difficulty and complexity of the problem suggests that you may find it easier to refactor your model.
If you have an ID for each "product", you could keep a history of skus and use date ranges to find the original and superseded values (I use "product" as a term for an item that may or may not have been superseded, not necessarily a physical inventory item)

In this case, you model would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE sku_history (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sku` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
) ENGINE = 'MyISAM';
```

to get the starting sku, you would need to join sku_history to a version of the same table, but grouped by product id and using the earliest datetime value, like this

```
SELECT 
    product_id,
    sku
FROM sku_history
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        product_id, 
        MIN(`datetime`) `datetime` 
    FROM sku_history
    GROUP BY product_id
) min USING (product_id, `datetime`)
```

To get the superseded sku, you would do the same, but swap the earliest datetime for the latest (change MIN() for MAX())

For the final table you would join these resultsets together on product_id and remove any results where the sku hasn't changed, like this:

```
SELECT
    original.sku,
    superseded.sku AS superseded_sku
FROM (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        sku
    FROM sku_history
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            product_id, 
            MIN(`datetime`) `datetime` 
        FROM sku_history
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) min USING (product_id, `datetime`)
) original
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        sku
    FROM sku_history
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            product_id, 
            MAX(`datetime`) `datetime` 
        FROM sku_history
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) max USING (product_id, `datetime`)
) superseded ON original.product_id = superseded.product_id
WHERE original.sku != superseded.sku;
```

If you want to find what the skus where between a specific date range (for example, between last month and this month) all you would need to do is to add a condition on datetime inside each of the subqueries (e.g. WHERE 'datetime' > '2015-03-01')